# In vb.net whats does it mean this symbol after the parameter thats been input ":="

Tags: .net, vb.net

Here a sample

```
Sub callMethod()
    methodName(param:="something")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are called Named arguements

> A named argument consists of an argument name followed by a colon and
>   an equal sign (:=), followed by the argument value.
>
> Named arguments are especially useful when you are calling a procedure
>   that has optional arguments. If you use named arguments, you don't
>   have to include commas to denote missing positional arguments. Using
>   named arguments makes it easier to keep track of which arguments you
>   passed and which you omitted.

[Understanding Named Arguments and Optional Arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251503.aspx)

> When you call a Sub or Function procedure, you can supply arguments
>   positionally, in the order they appear in the procedure's definition,
>   or you can supply the arguments by name without regard to position.
>
> For example, the following Sub procedure takes three arguments:

```
Sub PassArgs(strName As String, intAge As Integer, dteBirth As Date) 
 Debug.Print strName, intAge, dteBirth 
End Sub
```

> You can call this procedure by supplying its arguments in the correct
>   position, each delimited by a comma, as shown in the following
>   example:

```
PassArgs("Mary", 29, #2-21-69#)
```

> You can also call this procedure by supplying named arguments,
>   delimiting each with a comma.

```
PassArgs(intAge:=29, dteBirth:=#2/21/69#, strName:="Mary")
```